# how to write to file in an multithreaded environment

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a program that runs on multithread but all of them need to save results to same text file

I get access violation error

how can i avoid doing that

Comment: You did not get an access violation error, that would be rather bad.  You probably got an UnauthorizedAccessException.  Open the file only once and use a lock to prevent output from getting intermingled.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap file IO into a [lock statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx):

```
private static object _syncRoot = new object();
```

and then:

```
lock(_syncRoot)
{
    // do whatever you have to do with this file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the lock statement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is to simply make sure you have some locking construct (mutex, monitor, etc) against access to the file, then each thread can access it in isolation. This could either be accessing the same underlying Stream/TextWriter/etc, or could be opening/closing the file inside the locked region.

A more complex approach would be to have a dedicated writer thread, and a synchronised work queue. Then all threads can add to the queue and a single thread draughts and writes to the file. This means your main threads are only blocked while adding to a queue (very brief), rather than blocked on IO (slower). However, note that if the process exits abnormally, data in the queue may be lost.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading up on the ReaderWriterLock class or the ReaderWriterLockSlim class which is faster but has some gotchas, I believe it would suit your needs perfectly.

[ReaderWriterLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx)

[ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx)

Comment: This is wrong; all the threads here are writers. Reader/writer locks only benefit you if reads vastly outnumber writes. In this case, all access will need to be writes (so exclusive). This just ***adds*** overhead. A vanilla lock (Monitor) would be far preferable.

Comment: I would be hard pressed to say any of these approaches where flat out "wrong".  Yes the monitor does provide better performance in write only circumstances, but at a level that will only be felt very high contention situations.

Comment: if all the access is "write", then sure it'll still *work*, but it is using the wrong tool